# Django Rest Framework ListField and DictField

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am having struggle with understanding `ListField` and `DictField`. I want to use it as a field on a serializer. I have a `ListField` which probably will contain many `DictField`. I tried to write a serializer as below:

```
class StopOncomingSerialier(serializers.Serializer):
    idn = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    buses = serializers.ListField(
        child=serializers.DictField(
            idn=serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True),
            stops_left=serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
        ),
    read_only=True
    )
```

I know, it does not make sense, since the documentation says `DictField` and `ListField` take `child` as argument. And so, the code above naturally raised error:

> **TypeError:** __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'stops_left'

#### Desired Output

```
{
    "idn": 1,
    "buses": [
        {"idn": 11, "stops_left": 4},
        {"idn": 12, "stops_left": 15}
    ]
}
```

How to achieve this? `buses` is a list and might contain as many elements as I want.

---

## Environment

- python 3.5.1
- django 1.9.6
- django-rest-framework 3.3.3

Comment: Shouldn't `child` be a serializer class rather than a field instance? **[edit: no it shouldn't, my bad]**

Comment: [Documentation example](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#listfield) puts `Field` instead of `Serializer`, that is why I did that, but I am going to try with `Serializer` to know if it works.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I think instead of doing that, you should **use nested serializers**.

Create a `BusSerializer` having fields `idn` and `stops_left`. Then include this serializer in your `StopOncomingSerializer` as `buses` field with `many=True` argument to handle multiple `buses` data.

```
class BusSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    idn = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    stops_left = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)


class StopOncomingSerialier(serializers.Serializer):
    idn = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    buses = BusSerializer(many=True)
```

Comment: Could you give the example how to post data using `StopOncomingSerialier` ?. I have tried your solution and I got empty list if I get the data from `.validated_data` but I can get raw json if I get the data from `request.data`

Comment: For sample data, please check this [SO link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37630032/adding-many-serializer-to-a-nested-serializer-field) which is related to this question. Also, did you call the `.is_valid()` method on the serializer to access the `validated_data`?

Comment: @RahulGupta And what the model should look like then, if you don't mind me asking? I'm currently using MongoDB and would like to write a json Document (not plain text) into my database. Is it possible?

Comment: @Albert For mongodb, you need to use [DRF-Mongoengine](https://github.com/umutbozkurt/django-rest-framework-mongoengine). Also, it would be helpful if you post another question with the corresponding models.

Comment: @RahulGupta I did yesterday, here's my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50091847/how-to-deal-with-deeply-nested-jsons-in-django-being-used-together-with-djongo-f
I made an edit there. Would you please take a look?

Comment: Nested structure supports only ModelSerializer, as it implemented it with a function called build_nested_field. And restrictions were set in ModelSerializer.get_fields funtion.