# Adding Many Serializer to A Nested Serializer Field

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

#### serializers.py

```
class BusOncomingSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    idn = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    stops_left = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)


class StopOncomingSerialier(serializers.Serializer):
    idn = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    buses = BusOncomingSerializer(many=True)
```

I have my serializer instances which are valid in a list as below:

```
buses_serializers = [bus1, bus2, bus3]
# busX means instance of BusOncomingSerializer and they are valid.
```

I am trying to add these `BusOncomingSerializer` instances to a single `StopOncomingSerializer` instance by:

```
serializer = serializers.StopOncomingSerializers(data={"idn": 1, "buses": buses_serializers})
```

And I run `is_valid()`. However, it raises:

> **TypeError:** BusOncomingSerializer(data={'idn': 285, 'stops_left': 7}): idn = IntegerField(read_only=True) stops_left = IntegerField(read_only=True) is not JSON serializable

Should I not add my serializer instances with a list, is there another way?

---

## Environment

- python 3.5.1
- django 1.9.5
- django-rest-framework 3.3.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing the data incorrectly to `StopOncomingSerializer`. Instead of passing `bus` instances, you should pass the values as list of dictionaries.

**Sample Data format:**

```
{
    'idn': 7, 
    'buses': [
        {'idn':3, 'stops_left': 3}, 
        {'idn': 4, 'stops_left':6}
    ]
}
```

**On Python Shell:**

```
In [5]: data = {'idn': 7, 'buses': [{'idn':3, 'stops_left': 3}, {'idn': 4, 'stops_left':6}]}

In [6]: s1 = StopOncomingSerialier(data=data)

In [7]: s1.is_valid()
Out[7]: True
```

Comment: I initialize a `StopOncomingSerializer` instance as `serializer = serializers.StopOncomingSerialier(data={"idn": stop_idn, "buses": buses})`. Could you give an example based on that? | Note: `buses` is a list containing many `BusOncomingSerializer` instances.

Comment: I have added an sample example done on shell. Maybe this should help.

Comment: @ErdinEray pass whole structure, do not try to parse busses before, let serializer do its work and parse all deep structures