# Nested Serializer in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am trying to make a nested serializer but when I run the following code it gives me an empty list. I tried to replicate the solution of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37629501/django-rest-framework-listfield-and-dictfield) and my problem is exactly similar

The only difference is in that answer serializer.Serializer is used but I am using Model Serializer

```
class hhhSerializer(serializers.Modelserializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    name = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = ItemBatch
        fields = ('id','name')


class dispatchhistorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    truck_name = ReadOnlyField(source='truck_name.name')
    truck_type = ReadOnlyField(source='truck_type.name')

    items = hhhSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = DispatchPlan
        fields = "__all__"
```

Output:

```
        "id": 35,
        "truck_name": "24 ft mxl 14 Ton",
        "truck_type": "Container",
        "items": [
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {},
            {}
        ],
```

Comment: Avoid using names like `hhhSerializer`

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the field explicitly at `DispatchHistorySerializer.Meta.fields`; now, as personal recommendation *avoid always `"all"` in the field list*

This code should work (I had renamed your classes to comform python convention)

```py
class HhhSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    name = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = ItemBatch
        fields = ('id','name')


class DispatchHistorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    truck_name = ReadOnlyField(source='truck_name.name')
    truck_type = ReadOnlyField(source='truck_type.name')
    items = HhhSerializer(many=True)  # 2) here we say how to serialize 'items'

    class Meta:
        model = DispatchPlan
        fields = ('id', 'truck_name', 'truck_type', 'items',)  # 1) here we say: include 'items' please
```

**EDIT**: if using `ModelSerializer`, define which model in the `Meta` class; if it isn't a ModelSerializer, use a simple `Serializer` instead